# Number of outputed JInternalFrames depending on number of input

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, io, jinternalframe

How can I display a number of JInternalFrames depending on the number of inputs?
For example I have to input 3 text files , then I should output 3 JInternalFrames containing the respective contents of the text files? TIA

**********[UPDATE]**********
I already did it but a new problem showed up. JInternalFrames only move freely on absolute(null) layout but when I display more, the panel cannot be scrolled even if some of the JInternalFrames are outside of the parameter. I placed a panel in a Scrollable pane but the scroll function is not working. I have already set the scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBA‌​R_ALWAYS); scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_A‌​S_NEEDED);

Comment: Please post what you have attempted and where you're having problems. TIA

Comment: I suggest you start by taking a look at [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) and refine you question a little more to identify the area you are having problems with

Comment: I am currently displaying JInternalFrames upon a button click. My problem is that it should depend on inputs. Like 3 text files will produce 3 JInternalframes

Comment: So when I try to produce multiple frames, I end up producing them in the same location. Do you guys know how to do an offset bounds?

Comment: As noted in [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) you can use `java.awt.Component.setLocation(int x, int y)`

Comment: Some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+JInternalFrame+offset).

Comment: I already did it but a new problem showed up. JInternalFrames only move freely on absolute(null) layout but when I display more, the panel cannot be scrolled even if some of the JInternalFrames are outside of the parameter. I placed a panel in a Scrollable pane but the scroll function is not working. I have already set the  scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
 
  scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);